# Stop element from being fixed once scrolled past value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed .widget element that remains visible at all times. Currently however, it scrolls over the footer area. My goal is to stop the widget before it hits the footer.

**CSS**

```
.widget {
position:fixed;
height:450px;
width:300px;
}

footer {
height:450px;
width:100%;
}
```

My route I'm taking is currently:

**jQuery**

```
var $bodyheight = $('body').height();
var $footerheight = $('footer').height();
var $widgetheight = $('.game_widget').height();
var $pageheight = $bodyheight - $footerheight - $widgetheight;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  console.log($(this).scrollTop())
});
```

My next step would be to loop through to see if scrollTop > $pageheight then update some CSS.

Is this the best way of going about this? Is there a cleaner/simpler way to achieve the same result?

Comment: According to me, it's a good solution. I don't think you can do that easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this quite simply. Inside the scroll function I set 2 variables, one for the position of the fixed element, the other for the position of the footer. These return the exact value from how far the top of the element is from the top of the page. For the fixed element I need to know the distance to the bottom of this element so I also include the height.

```
var $fixedpos = $(".game_widget").offset().top + $('.game_widget').height();
var $footerpos = $("footer").offset().top - 25; // 25 accounts for margin
```

Using a simple if/else the CSS is updated to display none/initial depending on whether $fixedpos > $footerpos (i.e. the fixed element is overlapping the footer).

```
if ($fixedpos > $footerpos) {
    $('.game_widget').css('display','none');
} else {
    $('.game_widget').css('display','initial');
}
```

This works, however there is a 'flicking' effect as the fixed element overlaps the footer. This is due to the function executing extremely rapidly. The solution to the flicker is to use this simple 'throttling' plugin that adds a short delay (of your choice) between each execution of a function - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

You then just need to bind the on scroll function to the throttle:

```
function scrolling() {
  console.log($(".game_widget").offset().top + $('.game_widget').height());
  console.log($("footer").offset().top - 25);

  var $fixedpos = $(".game_widget").offset().top + $('.game_widget').height();
  var $footerpos = $("footer").offset().top - 25;

  if ($fixedpos > $footerpos) {
    $('.game_widget').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('.game_widget').css('display', 'initial');
  }

};

$(window).on('scroll', $.throttle(250, scrolling)); // 250ms between executing the function

});
```

This 250ms delay stops the function from executing so rapidly that the flickering effect occurs.

Hope this helps others trying to solve this problem.